# iphone, check values of cellId / Lac

Tags: iphone, cellid

I can get radio Informations cellId, Lac, MNC, MCC on iOS. And I'd like to know How can I check if values are correct ?

Thanks

Comment: for example, I have cellId = 1026  lac = 243  Mnc=208   mcc=20. I compared values with FieldTest and it's ok. Is there another way to check these values ? Is FieldTest reliable ?

Comment: @nico24: Hi Nico! Can you help poorDeveloper with getting cellId and LAC? He's looking for this info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399659/get-cellid-mcc-mnc-lac-and-network-in-ios-5-1#comment18332124_13399659

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13399659/4002424
this code is ok to get the cell information, you can try.